# How can I create categories and subcategories in django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am building a simple website for a car marketplace. I have written the brand, series and car models. (I purposefully want to treat each of them as seperate models.) Whenever I create a car in the admin panel I want to be able to pick a car brand - let's say Mercedes - and when I choose the brand I want the next option to be only the series of Mercedes not the series of other cars.

Here is a representation of my code so far:

```
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Series(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    series = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    series = models.ForeignKey(Series, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a [**`ChainedForeignKey`** <sup>[readthedocs.io]</sup>](https://django-smart-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#chainedforeignkey-options) instead from the [**`django-smart-selects`** package <sup>[readthedocs.io]</sup>](https://django-smart-selects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html):

```
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey


class Car(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    series = ChainedForeignKey(
        Series,
        chained_field='brand',
        chained_model_field='brand',
        show_all=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

Comment: I pip installed smart_selects but it only works for django versions <4.0

Comment: That is quite strange since they even test it with `4.0`: https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects/blob/master/.github/workflows/test.yml#L13

Comment: Looks like it has a compatibilty issues with django 5.0 which I am using: https://github.com/jazzband/django-smart-selects/issues/353

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a brief idea of your model hierarchy but just need to implement it. This is something Django does out of the box, you shouldn't need a 3rd party package to maintain this.

Start by reading about [models in Django,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/) especially Primary and Secondary/Foreign keys.

You will link each subsequent model through a foreign key to the primary model using a many-to-many mapping. Set your main primary key as the car (at the bottom level). Given it's a marketplace, set something like a UUID or BigInt as this unique ID as you will likely have a lot of values.

I would skip the junction tables approach and just create a linkage in your models, something like this:

```
class cars(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    series = models.ManyToManyField("series", related_name="cars", blank=True)
    brand = models.ManyToManyField("brand", related_name="cars", blank=True)

class series(models.Model):
    your model here


class brand(models.Model):
    your model here
```

Then you can surface this in your Django admin and create relations there. Eventually you can surface this to the end user in custom css/html and allow selections.